# How can we detect mouse double click in python?

Tags: python, ondoubleclick

I have been using **win32api** for single clicks. But I was not able to find a particular Virtual key code for double click. Is there some other way out?

Comment: have you tried using the function `LeftClick()` twice one after another ? (Try to include some code so we can provide you an adequate answer)

Comment: if module don't have this function then you have to measure time between clicks and if it smaller then some value then treat it as double click. But then problem is how to recognize double click and single click because it would need timer to execute function assigned to single click after some time when there is no second click.